# Save a formatted String to a LocalDate

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, formatter, localdate

I have a `DateConverter` class:

```
public class DateConverter extends StringConverter<LocalDate> {

    String pattern = "EEE, dd. MM. uuuu";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern,Locale.US);

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDate object) {
        try {
            return formatter.format(object);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return "";
        }      
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
        try {
            return LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getPattern(){
        return pattern;
    }

}
```

And I have this piece of code:

```
allProd.forEach((prod) -> {
    DateConverter dc = new DateConverter();
    LocalDate onMarket = dc.fromString(dc.toString(prod.getOnMarket()));
    System.out.println("localdate:" + onMarket);
    System.out.println("string:"+dc.toString(onMarket));
}
```

Which prints this:

```
localdate:2012-11-08
string:Thu, 08. 11. 2012
localdate:2011-11-13    
string:Sun, 13. 11. 2011
localdate:2002-04-11
string:Thu, 11. 04. 2002
```

What I want is that my `LocalDate` value is formatted like the string value is. Because I have a class which has a `LocalDate` field and the field should always be formatted. So I don't want to change the field datatype to string.

Comment: Why don't you just output the `dc.toString(prod.getOnMarket())` in your sample code? A date in itself isn't formatted, it's a set of values. If you want a consistent representation, you can store the formatted date in a `String` field and then parse that in your `getDate()` methods.

Comment: @daniu So you suggest that I change the datatype to a string in my class?

Comment: What do you mean by "a localdate field and the field should always be formatted" ? `LocalDate` has its own internal structure, what you see in your console is how the `toString` implemented in `LocalDate`.

Comment: @LolIPop65 No, it's just the only way to maintain format. What I suggest is you keep the `LocalDate` field and use your `DateTimeFormatter` in all places you need to display the date.

Comment: @J-Alex oh I understand. I thought I could change the structure of the localdate so when I print the localdate it will look like the string value.

Comment: @daniu oh ok. I understand

Comment: You could create your own Locale say with country, language _and_ custom variant.  After `Locale.setDefault` using MessageFormat and such should work. However some experimenting required. LocalDate.toString will never work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. A `LocalDate` does not have and cannot have a format in it.

If you adhere to separation of model and presentation, it would also be incorrect to put the format into the date. The `LocalDate` is part of your model (I presume). The `EEE, dd. MM. uuuu` format belongs in your presentation. Your converter class bridges the two.

A `LocalDate` holds a value, a date in the calendar, nothing else. Much the same way as an `int` holds a value. For example, an `int` may hold the value 64458. For presentation you may format it into strings like 000000064458, +64458 or 64,458 or even 64458.00 or in hex. The `int` stays the same. In the same way your `LocalDate` stays the same no matter which formatting operations you do. You can have your desired format only in a `String` outside the `LocalDate`.

As a compromise you may fit your class with a `getFormattedDate` method that formats your date into a string. You decide whether this would blur the separation between model and presentation too much, or since the date should always be formatted, in this case it’s acceptable to you.

Comment: yes, you cannot format actual data but viewing you can manipulate it but it doesn't mean that you have modified the actual data.