# Format month of date to string of 3 first letters- Kotlin

Tags: date, kotlin, formatdatetime

I have this date "08/08/2019" and I want it to look like this: "08, Aug 2019", I tried to use `when` but wondered if there is an easier way to do this? I know it's a bit small question but I tried to find an answer over the internet and I couldn't find this.

Comment: I understand that 08/08/2019 is 08 Aug, but would 09 Aug be 09/08/2019 or 08/09/2019?

Comment: It's depend on what define when you write the format you want, as in the answer below

Comment: My search pretty quickly found [Java: Convert String Date to Month Name Year (MMM yyyy) [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113530/java-convert-string-date-to-month-name-year-mmm-yyyy), It seems to me that a couple of the answers might at least get you some of the way. Maybe you should train your searching abilities?

Comment: Maybe I should. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first, you need to convert the string to Date object then convert it to your format using the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

**Update**

```
val firstDate = "08/08/2019"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
val date = formatter.parse(firstDate)
val desiredFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM yyyy").format(date)
println(desiredFormat) //08, Aug 2019
```

old answer

```
val firstDate = "08/08/2019"
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
val date = formatter.parse(firstDate)
val desiredFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM yyyy").format(date)
println(desiredFormat) //08, Aug 2019
```

Comment: Is there a way to open it from an ```EditText``` element? I tried ```onClick``` but it works only on the second click

Comment: @ofir2471 I didn't get your question
what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry mistaken, I'm doing date picker and forgot I didn't ask it here, sorry, I'll delete it

Comment: That looks good. No further comments from me (but an upvote).

Answer (score 1):

### Use the predefined localized formats and java.time

```
    Locale englishIsrael = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IL");
    DateTimeFormatter shortDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(englishIsrael);
    DateTimeFormatter mediumDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(englishIsrael);

    String dateStringWeHave = "08/08/2019";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStringWeHave, shortDateFormatter);
    String dateStringWeWant = date.format(mediumDateFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateStringWeWant);
```

Sorry about the Java syntax, I trust you to translate. Output is:

> 8 Aug 2019

It’s not exactly the `08, Aug 2019` that you asked for. However, Java usually has a good idea about what format people around the globe expect, so my first suggestion is you consider settling with this one (frankly `08` and comma also looks a bit weird to me, but what do I know?)

The other feature that the code snippet demonstrates is the use of `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I warmly recommend java.time over the long outdated date-time classes like `Date` and in particular `SimpleDateFormat`. They were poorly designed. There was a reason why they were replaced.

If your users say they absolutely want `08, Aug 2019`, you need to specify that through a format pattern string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter handBuiltFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM uuuu", englishIsrael);
    String dateStringWeWant = date.format(handBuiltFormatter);
```

Now we do get exactly the output you asked for:

> 08, Aug 2019

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Tried ```var date = event.date?.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM uuuu"))``` but the date stays the same, ```16.09.2019```

Comment: Of course the event date stays the same. A `LocalDate` is immutable and also cannot have a format. You can have a format only in a `String`. See [Save a formatted String to a LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098566/save-a-formatted-string-to-a-localdate).

Comment: With the old-fashioned way using ```SimpleDateFormat``` you can control it the ```string``` changes, so I'l probably gonna stick with it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get that, and I’m afraid you misunderstood. If I understand Kotlin syntax correctly, `var date = event.date?.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM uuuu"))` will also give you the string you want. I only said “string”.

Comment: Yes I understood that the date is immutable and I can only change the way I see it in strings, but the strings stays the same without any formatting.

Comment: I’m sorry, I still don’t understand. Which string (or result of other type) are you getting from `var date = event.date?.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM uuuu"))`? As I said, in my Java code `dateStringWeWant` becomes `08, Aug 2019`.

Comment: I have this date: 16.09.2019,
I want it to look like this: 16, Sep 2019. When I do the code above it stays 16.09.2019

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193675/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-ofir2471).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's SimpleDataFormat class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
val myDateStr = "08/08/2019"
val parsedDateObj = SimpleDateFromat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(myDateStr)
val formattedDateStr = SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM yyyy").format(parsedDateObj) // "08, Aug 2019"
```

Comment: I get this error: ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date```

Comment: @ofir2471 Ah sorry, wrote the answer from memory, I forgot that it takes an object! Edited my answer.