# How to format Simple Date Formatter in Java as dd-3 letter month-yyyy?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a simple date formatter with the following format:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
//accessExpiryDate is a Date object
DATE_FORMATTER.format(accessExpiryDate);
```

And it is formatting the date as yyyy-MM-dd. But I want to format the date such as **"1 Jun 2019"**. day + first 3 letter of the month + year.

How can i achieve that? Is there a simple way/method/class or should i write my custom date formatter method?

Comment: I suggest reading the [documentation for SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - but also, if you can possibly use java.time instead of java.text/java.util, you'll have a better experience.

Comment: my date is a just Date class.

Comment: Have you tried changing the DATE_FORMAT from "yyyy-MM-dd" to "d MMM YYYY"?

Comment: @abidinberkay: Yes, I'm suggesting that if you can possibly move to `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.time.Instant` etc you'll have a better experience.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of [Format month of date to string of 3 first letters- Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207152/format-month-of-date-to-string-of-3-first-letters-kotlin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### java.time

Don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. As Jon Skeet said, move to java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for a better experience.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM u", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JUNE, 1);
    System.out.println(ld.format(dateFormatter));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 1 Jun 2019

A number of format pattern letters including `M` for month can yield either a number or a text depending on how many letters you put in the format pattern string (this is true for both `DateTimeFormatter` and the legacy `SimpleDateFormat`). So `MM` gives you two-digit month number, while `MMM` gives you a month abbreviation (often three letters, but could be longer or shorter in some languages).

If you are getting an old-fashioned `Date` object from a legacy API that you either cannot change or don’t want to upgrade just now, you may convert it like this:

```
    Date accessExpiryDate = getFromLegacyApi();
    LocalDate ld = accessExpiryDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
```

The rest is as before. And now you’ve embarked on using the modern API and can migrate your code base in this direction at your own pace.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089932/simpledateformat-format-month-september-jdk16

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified the date format as `yyyy-MM-dd`, it is formatted as that. Just fix your date format to the expected formatting.

e.g: `d MMM yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by @JonSkeet, you should read the API documentation.
Anyway, the format should be in your case `d MMM yyyy`.