# Why isn’t DateTimeFormatter formatting my String?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, localdate, java-time

I have a simple Date String `headerValues[5]="24.11.1946"`. I just want to convert, parse it to a Date Object. 
So I use

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = ofPattern(("dd.MM.yyyy");
  headerLine.setStartDate(LocalDate.parse(headerValues[5],datePattern));
```

Output is `2012-04-25` not my desired `24.11.1946`???

Why???

### EDIT

I tried this...

```java
DateTimeFormatter datePattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
String date = "24.11.1946";
System.out.println("Date = "+ LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern));
```

Output is...

> Date = 1946-11-24

Comment: Shouldn't the second line of the code you posted be: `headerLine.setStartDate(LocalDate.parse(headerValues[5], formatter));` ?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line of the code you posted be: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");` ?

Comment: yes it was typo still not working still same output

Comment: Then I suggest you post a [mcve].

Comment: DateTimeFormatter datePattern =              
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
        String date = "24.11.1946";
        System.out.println("Date = "+ LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern)); 
Try this output is Date = 1946-11-24

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add your last comment. Never mind, I did it for you. So what is the problem with the output you are getting?

Comment: I want the pattern dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: I read about Date toString method do i have to override it or just use pattern which is obviously not working ? For what is this pattern?

Comment: A `LocalDate` cannot have a format. When you concatenate `"Date = "+ LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern)`, you are implicitly calling `toString` on the parsed `LocalDate` object, and `toString` always produces the format that you saw, `1946-11-24`. So you are asking the impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a formatted String to a LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098566/save-a-formatted-string-to-a-localdate)

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code...

```
LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern)
```

creates a `LocalDate` instance.

Hence in this line of your code...

```
System.out.println("Date = "+ LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern));
```

you are actually calling method `toString()` of class `LocalDate`.

From the *javadoc* of that method...

> The output will be in the ISO-8601 format `uuuu-MM-dd`.

You don't want that format. You want the format of your `datePattern` object. Hence you should change the last line of the code you posted to...

```
System.out.println(datePattern.format(LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern)));
```

In other words, the same `DateTimeFormatter` object can be used both to parse a `String` to a date and to format a date to a `String`.

Comment: Hi i found out that the DateTimeFormatter.format method is returning a String i need a LocalDate Object ???

Comment: is there a way to make an 24.11.1946 object and save it as is without formatting Strings?

Comment: This code - `LocalDate.parse(date,datePattern)` - returns a `LocalDate` object. Is that what you want? Do you just want a `LocalDate` object?

Comment: a `Date` itself rarely (if ever) stores the actual string or format of the moment in time - it usually stores a long which is some amount away from an epoch. You need to use that formatter to convert between your desired string representation and the actual `Date` object that represents it; if you want to simplify this, then make something which wraps your date objects and provides that functionallity

Comment: @Rogue I think you need to explain that to the OP - and not to me :-)

Comment: @Rogue The OP shouldn’t want the functionality of a date object with a stored format. The OP should keep model — the date — and user interface — the format — separate (in all but the simplest throw-away programs).